# How to print three lists in rows with 3 columns having commas and no brackets

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have three Python lists

```
ListA
ListB
ListC
```

All the lists have same number of elements.

I want to print them in the following shape:

```
a0, b0, c0,

a1, b1, c1,

.
.
.

an, bn, cn
```

so there is a comma between elements and after each row except the last one.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

You can do it by using `zip` and  two different joins:

```
',\n'.join([', '.join(items) for items in zip(a, b, c)])
```

or as rafaelc suggested:

```
',\n'.join(map(', '.join, zip(a, b, c)))
```

### Explanation:

#### `zip`

`zip` groups the elements of the different iterables you provide by position.

```
zip(['a0', 'a1', 'a2', ...], ['b0', 'ba1', 'b2', ...], ['c0', 'c1', 'c2', ...])
```

returns:

```
('a0', 'b0', 'c0'), ('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), ('a2', 'b2', 'c2'), ...
```

Depends on your Python version it may return it as a list or as a generator but both are iterables so that shouldn't be a problem.

#### `map`

`map` applies the function passed as first arguments to each element of the iterable passed as second argument and return the resulting iterable.

So it will apply `', '.join` to `('a0', 'b0', 'c0')`, then it will apply `', '.join` to `('a1', 'b1', 'c1')`, ...

```
', '.join(('a0', 'b0', 'c0')), ', '.join(('a1', 'b1', 'c1')), ', '.join(('a2', 'b2', 'c2')), ...
```

and with the other join we would have:

```
',\n'.join(   ', '.join(('a0', 'b0', 'c0')), ', '.join(('a1', 'b1', 'c1')), ', '.join(('a2', 'b2', 'c2')), ...   )
```

#### List comprehension

The list comprehension is what is used in the first solution instead of map, applying ', '.join to each element of the iterable.

```
[', '.join(item) for item in zip(a, b, c)]
```

is equivalent to:

```
map(', '.join, zip(a, b, c))
```

except that the list comprehension returns a list and the map call returns an iterable, but that doesn't make any difference as the outter join accepts iterables and lists are also iterables.

#### `join`

`join` makes a string concatenating the elements of the iterable passed as an argument using as a separator the string from which it was called.

```
"-".join(['Hello', 'World'])
```

returns:

```
'Hello-World'
```

Applying the inner joins:

```
',\n'.join( [ 'a0, b0, c0', 'a1, b1, c1', 'a2, b2, c2', ... ] )
```

And applying the outter one

```
'a0, b0, c0,\na1, b1, c1,\na2, b2, c2,\n...'
```

#### Some comments:

They may be just part of the simplification of the problem you did to post it here:

- Do not use PascalCase names for variables, use snake_case.
- Try to avoid using a variable that defines the type of variable.

Comment: That's how I'd do it. Maybe `',\n'.join(map(', '.join, zip(*lists)))` is a little more compact, but exact same logic ;]

Comment: @rafaelc Added your alternative way to the solution with proper credit

Answer (score 1):

You could zip it into row elements, then use '%' for format the row output. The easiest way I can think of to drop the last comma and newline it to read the output to the -2 position. Additionally, this won't error if the lists are of length zero (works in edge case).

Source:

```
ListA = ['a0','a1','a2']
ListB = ['b0','b1','b2']
ListC = ['c0','c1','c2']

output = ""

for row in zip(ListA, ListB, ListC):
    output += "%s, %s, %s,\n" % row

output = output[:-2]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
a0, b0, c0,
a1, b1, c1,
a2, b2, c2
```

Answer (score 0):

Given all elements have the same length, you can just set it in a single print within a for loop for the `range(len())` of any list:

```
ListA = ['a0','a1','a2']
ListB = ['b0','b1','b2']
ListC = ['c0','c1','c2']


for i in range(len(ListA)):
    if i < (len(ListA)-1):
        print(ListA[i]+", "+ListB[i]+", "+ListC[i]+",")
    else:
        print(ListA[i]+", "+ListB[i]+", "+ListC[i])
```

Output:

```
a0, b0, c0,
a1, b1, c1,
a2, b2, c2
```

Comment: He added a final comma in every line except for the last one, which would not be straightforward to do with a self-handled loop.

Comment: Yes, I noted it after re-reading your comment, you are right. The edit version works well now, just a matter of adding an if statement.

Comment: I try to avoid handling edge cases with conditionals but you are right, you can do it this way too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake and first and helping me solve it. Was the downvote yours?

Comment: No, if I downvote from some mistakes that are solved I remove the downvotes when they are solved but in this case it wasn't me.

Answer (score 0):

```
la = [1,2,3]
lb = [4,5,6]
lc = [7,8,9]

# zip the three lists
ls = zip(la, lb, lc)

#loop through the iterator
for i, v in enumerate(ls):
    # convert to string and replace the left curved bracket
    v = str(v).replace("(", "")

    if (len(la) - i) == 1:
        print(v.replace(")", ""))
        continue
    # replace the right curved bracket with ',' if it's not the last
    print(v.replace(")", ","))
```

output

```
1, 4, 7,
2, 5, 8,
3, 6, 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest:

```
listA =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
listB =[11,2,3,4,5,6,7]
listC =[111,2,3,4,5,6,7]
length = len(listA) 
i = 0

# Iterating using while loop 
while i < length: 
    if (i<length-1):
        print(str(listA[i]) + ','+ str(listB[i])+ ','+ str(listC[i])+",")
    else:
         print(str(listA[i]) + ','+ str(listB[i])+ ','+ str(listC[i]))
    i += 1
```